# How to get all bus stops name between two stops?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using Google map direction API for getting all routes detail from source to destination, everything is fine but i have one additional requirement i.e getting all bus stops name in between two stops as it shows in Google map Transit Direction. Is there any way to get it. I'm working for Singapore location.

this is the response:- 
[image]

I need details of bus stop as shown below there are 18 bus stops:-

[image]

Output i have :-

[image]

i want to get all the bus stops name and there location so that i could set alarm for any stops by using there location.

Answer (score 1):

The response should have all the stops in an array within `transit_details`. You can parse the results and output it from there.

I fetched and parsed results for a sample query from [Google docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#RequestParameters) and it has the stop names in "name" elem under `transit_details`.

```html
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Brooklyn&destination=Queens&mode=transit&key=API_KEY
```

Useful Links:
[Steps & `transit_details`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Steps)
[Parsing JSON response](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/index#ParsingJSON)
[Fair based results biasing](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2015/01/transit-directions-improvements.html) (just interesting, if you want to include)

Comment: You could try Distance Matrix API.

Comment: Did you checked Distance Matrix have intermediate stops..?

Comment: So check here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#distance_matrix_results. "elements are children of rows, and correspond to a pairing of the row's origin with each destination." this line makes me assume it does. But I didn't get a chance to test.

Comment: transit_details does not return intermediate stops of a single transit leg.